# I'm not able to run WCF service on IIS 5.1

Tags: wcf, iis

I have WCF service that works fine on VS2008's Development Server, but after I deployed it on IIS 5.1 and ran the following error message comes up:

> This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.
>       Parameter name: item

The appropriate section in web.config file looks as following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Parus.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Parus.ServiceBehavior" name="Parus.Service">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Parus.IService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I've tried to follow this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2008/02/11/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site.aspx

But it's not working.

Does anybody know to resolve this issue?

Goran

Comment: from the link you've provided: The address of endpoints in the configuration file need to be complete URI. When porting your 3.0 or 3.5 workaround to 4.0 you need to keep this particular aspect.
 
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

Comment: I use .NET Framework 3.5. What do in that case?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to make double post. You already post the same problem at this place (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624645/i-cant-run-wcf-service-on-iis) and I say you to use svc file.